# Haskell to Scala

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming

Im new to Scala but I know something about functional programing thanks to Haskell and I'm looking for some examples, can you tell me how this would be in Scala?

```
scalarProduct :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Int
scalarProduct [] _ = 0
scalarProduct _ [] = 0
scalarProduct (x:xs) (y:ys) = if length(xs) == length (ys) then x*y + scalarProduct xs ys else 0

lessThan :: [Float] -> Float -> Int
lessThan [] _ = 0
lessThan (x:xs) n = if x < n then 1 + lessThan xs n else lessThan xs n


removeLast :: [a] -> [a]
removeLast [] = []
removeLast (x:xs) = if length(xs) == 0 then [] else [x] ++ removeLast xs


funcion :: Int -> Float
funcion x | x >= 6 = fromIntegral(product[9..x*2])
          | x > 0 = fromIntegral(x) ** (1/4)
          | x <= 0 = fromIntegral(product[1..(-x)]) * 5.0**fromIntegral(x)
```

Comment: I would start off looking here http://docs.scala-lang.org/cheatsheets/ its a pretty good quick reference guide if thats what you're interested in.

Comment: Don't try to learn a language by translating from another one: you are likely to produce non idiomatic code. Some Haskell patterns can be translated, yes, but I'd start from a Scala tutorial in the beginning.

Comment: `removeLast` can be done with `init`. i.e. `List(1,2,3).init` is `List(1,2)`.

Comment: 'lessThan` can be done with `count`. i.e. `List(1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4).count(_ < 1.3)` is `3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want literal transformations, I think the below is as close as you will get. Bear in mind you have to put this inside an object/class/trait for this to compile (or just past it into the REPL).

```
def scalarProduct(list1: List[Int], list2: List[Int]): Int = (list1,list2) match {
    case (Nil,_) => 0
    case (_,Nil) => 0
    case (x :: xs, y :: ys) => if (xs.length == ys.length) x*y + scalarProduct(xs,ys) else 0
}

def lessThan(floats: List[Float], bound: Float): Int = floats match {
    case Nil => 0
    case x :: xs => if (x < bound) 1 + lessThan(xs,n) else lessThan(xs,n)
}

def removeLast[A](list: List[A]): List[A] = list match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case x :: xs => if (xs.length == 0) Nil else List(x) ++ removeLast(xs)
}

def funcion(x: Int): Double = {
    if (x >= 6)
      (9 to x*2).product
    else if (x > 0)
      Math.pow(x,0.25)
    else
      (1 to -x).product.toDouble * Math.pow(5.0,x)
}
```

This code is pretty un-Scala-like. For example, the Scala way of doing the first three would probably be with an implicit conversion class `RichList[A]`. Also, these can all be done much more simply using library functions - but I don't think that's what you are looking for (else you would've used the corresponding library functions for the Haskell code).